# Using build number in a URL

Tags: grails, gsp

In Grails, I can get the build number from this:

```
<g:meta name="build.number"/>
```

However, i want to take the build.number and put it into a URL so I can then hyperlink to the actual build.

```
<a href="http://localhost/jenkins/builds/{build.number}/showall>click here fore build info</a>
```

Any ideas how I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this in gsp, you can try:

```
${g.meta([name: 'build.number'])}
```

So, your code would look like:

```
<a href="http://localhost/jenkins/builds/${g.meta([name: 'build.number'])}/showall">click here fore build info</a>
```